# How can one shorten the code when reading input?

Tags: c++

```
int testcases;
cin >> testcases;
```

Is there a way to shorten the above to one line? Or more generally, can anyone provide me a good resource where I can read about code shortage that doesn't necessarily affect the readability?

Comment: Not really, but I can make it longer: `if(int testcases; std::cin >> testcases) { ... }`

Comment: Not everything needs to be "shorter". Clarity trumps brevity.

Comment: Use Python  `testcases = input()`

Comment: @tadman that's why I said "that doesn't necessarily affect the readability"

Comment: Why do you need the code on one line?  Your bottleneck is waiting for the User, which trumps any kind of efficiency.  Is your platform space constrained?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a whole lot to shorten there; however if you were going to be writing many instances of the above, you could write a helper-function like this:

```
int readInt()
{
   int i;
   cin >> i;
   return i;
}
```

... then your many instances could be just one line apiece:

```
int testcases = readInt();
```

Comment: In practice might be worth adding an argument as to the stream to pull from, ergonomically, like `readInt(cin)`, so as to make it more flexible as well as clear where that data is coming from.

Comment: Interestingly, this would not make the code shorter than in Ted's comment because you will still need to write `int testcases = readInt(); if(cin) { /* use testcases */ }`. I'm also not sure if you can return an uninitialized variable without invoking UB (in case of a read error).

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica "_If extraction fails (e.g. if a letter was entered where a digit is expected), zero is written to value and `failbit` is set._" so returning it is ok even if extraction fails.

Answer (score 1):

Building on Jeremy's idea, you could make a function template that creates and reads into many variables at once:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

template<class... Types, size_t... I>
void readthem(std::istream& is, std::tuple<Types...>& rv, std::index_sequence<I...>) {
    // A C++17 fold expression
    (is >> ... >> std::get<I>(rv));
}

template<class... Types, class Indices = std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Types)>>
auto readvars(std::istream& is) {
    std::tuple<Types...> rv;      // A tuple consisting of the types you want
    readthem(is, rv, Indices{});
    if(not is) throw std::runtime_error("Input failed");
    return rv;
}

int main() {
    // read an int, a double and a std::string
    auto[i, d, s] = readvars<int, double, std::string>(std::cin);

    std::cout
        << i << '\n'
        << d << '\n'
        << s << '\n';
}
```